# multiprocessing python 3.6 on windows 10 not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I was working with python 3.6 on Linux, and I was using python's multiprocessing library, It was working until I switch to Windows 10. First, I thought it's because the multiprocessing library doesn't work the same way on Linux and Windows, so I make sure that all my variables are picklable but no results.

Then, I wanted to see if multiprocessing pool is working, 
I tried this code : (the basic example in multiprocessing doc)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

It didn't work and when I check the processors in the task manager, only 1% is used.

I also tried the `p.map_async`, it worked but when I try to get the results (`p.map_async().get()`) it doesn't work (RuntimeError)

Comment: Does the `RuntimeError` give you any more information? What happens with the code you've shown (does it freeze, or raise an exception)?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? Please do share.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre : where is the other location with the solution ?

Comment: ah, look at the top of the question. That's a known UI annoyance, people see "duplicate" but not the link which is at the top

Answer (score -2):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    results = p.imap(f,range(300))
    for item in results:
        print(item)
    p.close()
```

this will print items returned in order. if you print(p.imap(f,range(300)) it returns memory location of data. If you say p = Pool() it will start max number of processes your CPU can handle.

Comment: doesn't work on windows 10